# Clicking on a PictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I would like to know how I can make a PictureBox click using the Text box .

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
   {
       // I wanna a method to click on PictureBox1 here 
   }
}
```

Comment: Calling an event from another event is a bad idea.  If you want to run some code, put it in its own method and call it from each event.

Comment: Can you be more specefic please, I'am kinda new on C#

Comment: This is very simplified, if you need more let me know, but I have detailed it out in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an event from another event is a bad idea. (In fact, calling a user driven event in your code is always a bad idea).

If you want to run some code, put it in its own method and call it from each event.

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
   {
             MyPictureBoxCode();
   }
}
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          MyPictureBoxCode();
}
private void MyPictureBoxCode()
{
            //common code
}
```

The `PictureBox Click` event and the `Textbox2 Click` event must be tied in from your designer.cs.

Comment: But what does that "click" do?  Why is it important that it get clicked?

Comment: Don't worry , this is enough .
Thanks mate